# AngularJS not compiled on Android with PhoneGap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, mobile, phonegap

my Problem is that I've build an App with PhoneGap that is based on AngularJS - when I execute the App on my Android-Device the AngularJS-Part does completely not work....
on some devices it works but on my (for example) everywhere are just displayed these {{VARIABLE}}-texts and nothing works....
Anyone have an idea why this error appears and how to fix it?

Kind regards

Comment: Try to debug it on your device.

Comment: Hey, I did that and I got some javascript errors, because - I don't know why - my chromium didn't allow some statements (like default parameters, [...Array()] definition, etc.). I fixed these statements - but now I've got an error that is not really easy to fix....
It says invalid keyword "class", or exactly: 14:05:03.263 Debug SystemWebChromeClient 12452  file:///android_asset/www/js/xxx.js: Line 1 : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Comment: what's the version of android on your phone? if it's < 5.0 there are chances that the webview if using very old version of js engine so you'd have to add pollyfills to your project.in order to support older browsers.